# Populate ListView and their detail views with from multiple sqlite tables

Tags: android, sqlite, android-layout, android-listview

currently I'm searching for a solution to populate a ListView with content from 3 different SQLite tables. When tapped, each ListView item (row) should show the according detailed view (Activity), which is based on one of the three xml layouts.

Any suggestions?

Edit:

Currently I solved this for one type of Object/SQLite table. 
Fetching content from SQLite table into an ArrayList and pass it via putExtra to the detail activity, which handles setting texts/content.

The matching of the listView entry and starting the according detail view is solved with the arrayList index with matches to the listView index.

I'm not sure, if this is a proper solution. I guess it isn't...

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

   Intent typeOne_details_intent = new Intent(this, TypeOneDetailActivity.class);
   typeOne_result = new TypeOneResult();
   typeOne_result = typeOneResult_arr.get(position); 
   typeOne_details_intent.putExtra("result", TypeOneResult);
   startActivity(typeOne_details_intent);
}
```

How can I solve this to add typeTwoDetails and get a better matching between listview and according detailview?

Comment: Give us some more details. If I understand, you need to display data from 3 different tables in your listview. Then, when one of the row is clicked, this should open a new activity ?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please show us it will be more helpful

Comment: Exactly. for e.g.: Click on Row #1 --> opens new Activity of Type A and shows the according details. Click on Row #3 --> opens new Activity of Type C and shows the according details. Is that understandable? (I'm not a native speaker :/)

Comment: create your custom adapter. Surely that will meet your need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Custom Adapter that that can determine what Activity to start, set custom row view, etc. One way, you could create a row object Interface, and check the Object type to determine the layout for the row and set things such as the onClick listener and which Activity to launch.

Quick example below:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter<ListObjectInterface>{
...
ListObjectInterface data[];
....

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ListObjectInterface[] data) {
    ...
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ... /* do things. such as check if instance is present, etc. */

    ListObjectInterface object = data[position];

    if (object instanceOf TypeA) {
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceIdA, parent, false);
        ...
        ... /* get View objects and set Button listener to launch Activity A */
    } else if (object instanceOf TypeB) {
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceIdB, parent, false);
        ...
        ... /* get View objects and set Button listener to launch Activity B */
    } ... /* etc */

    ... /* more logic */

    return row;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I changed the code a bit. I'm checking for instance type in onItemClick().